# looping a string to an int amount of times and shortening it

Tags: java

If I input a string *str* and an int *n*, I need to create a loop that will print the beginning of the string *n* times, with the first *n* chars, then the first *n - 1*, then *n - 2*, and so on, until it prints just the first character.

So for example, "Apples" and "3" would result in "AppApA".

I have created the following, which works... somewhat. "n" being the int.

```
int i = 0;
while(i <= n)
{
    System.out.println(str.substring(0, Math.min(str.length(), n)));
    n = n - 1;
    i++;
}
```

This works for ints <= 2; if I input a string like "Chocolate" and the int 3, I will get "ChoCh" when I should be getting "ChoChC".

This has had me stumped for about 30 minutes. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `i` variable. You need to run the loop until the substring's length is 1, so:

```
while (n > 0)
{
    System.out.println(str.substring(0, Math.min(str.length(), n)));
    n = n - 1; // n-- would do the same thing here
}
```

Comment: thanks, i guess i was looking it at it the wrong way. Will tick when i can

Answer (score 2):

Since you both increment `i` and decrement `n`, your loop only happens roughly `n/2` times. This might have been clearer to you if you had tried in a debugger with a larger value of `n`, obviously paying particular attention to the loop condition.